# how to access bug data from bugzilla using python

Tags: python, bugzilla

i need to access bugzilla (server) data using python. what ways can use to do this. Is we can use XML-RPC or need layer by layer of understanding

Answer (score 0):

If it's new version of bugzilla (>=5), and it's configured to give access to API, you can use it: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:REST_API

Overwise, you'll have to use some library to download html pages from bugzilla, make requests and imitate a web-browser to acquire the data.

At first sight, this library could help you: https://github.com/amrollah/bugzilla-crawler

Comment: my bugzilla version is 4.4,my bugzilla running in "http://10.98.100.119" this server. i need to get bug data from that server using python, please help me, is it possible. am not getting any clue. every time am facing error:

Comment: raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='landfill.bugzilla.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bugzill
ectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0247C670>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10060] A con
he connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to

Comment: for Python2.7,Bugzilla server version4.4. unable to install crawler. which requires python3.4

Comment: Can you open your bugzilla site in a web browser?

Comment: yes, bugzilla server(http://10.98.100.119/PTS_RT_CSP_Sprint_Lab/bugzilla/), i need a sample python code to get bugs information from this SERVER_URL. any webservice possible XMLRPC/JSONRPC/REST. tried with XMLRPC but ending up with Connectionerror, mentioned above

Comment: You can try this module https://github.com/python-bugzilla/python-bugzilla